# How can I get the client IP using PHP?

Tags: php, remote-client

I have a webpage with PHP and im trying to get the client IP, but what I get is the server GATEWAY ip address (192.168.0.1).

This is what I have at the office:

ISP ---> ISP router ---> My router(192.168.0.1) ----> (192.168.0.2)My server.

I tryed all this lines, but I wasnt able to get the real ip, only  SERVER GATEWAY ip.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']
$_SERVER['GATEWAY_INTERFACE']
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']
$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET']
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']
$_SERVER['HTTP_CONNECTION']
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
$_SERVER['HTTPS']
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']
$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADMIN']
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] 
$_SERVER['SERVER_SIGNATURE']
$_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED']
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST']
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] 
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']
$_SERVER['AUTH_TYPE']
```

The following variables are "undefined":

```
-HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
-HTTP_CLIENT_IP
-HTTP_X_REAL_IP
-HTTPS
-REMOTE_HOST
-PATH_TRANSLATED
-PHP_AUTH_DIGEST
-PHP_AUTH_USER
-PHP_AUTH_PW
-AUTH_TYPE
```

EDIT: tried "var_dump($_SERVER)" and cannot find the client IP address :(

EDIT 2: I was googling a bit, and I "found the answer". What the user Martin Hohenberg said is right.  In the NAT proccess the Headers are destroyed so my server is unable to read the original IP address. At the moment I dont know a posible solution to this problem without moving the server to the front.

Comment: already answered http://stackoverflow.com/a/3003233/1894905

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are making a request from the machine where the server is running, then `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` will obviously contain your own IP address, which is 192.168.0.1

Comment: Im making the request from external networks, and I get the server's gateway address

Answer (score 2):

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-php)

Try

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

[Read more](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

```
function getUserIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) //if from shared
    {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //if from a proxy
    {
        return $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
        return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
}
```

Please check the read more link and the Question link

Comment: as I said, that returns server gateway IP, not the client IP

Comment: @Redder that hints that your server is behind some sort of NAT - which means that the TCP header is getting rewritten, essentially loosing the original client's IP

Comment: @Dasun - I tried all those server variables, and I have the same problem.

Comment: @MartinHohenberg - As far as I know, every router does NAT to translate public netowrk to private network. So why this works in other's networks and not in this one? Maybe a router conf problem??